# is there a way to find a column index in a DF which its entire values match another column using python

Tags: python, pandas

please excuse my humble knowledge of python
so the point is finding column_x index that all its values match column_1, within the same df, then I can use drop to drop columns from column_x till the end df.drop(df[column_x:-1])

any ideas folks?

thx

##data_sample##

```
#     A      B  C   D
#    0     one  0   0
#    2     two  2   4
#    4     two  4   8
#    6     one  6  12
#    7   three  7  14
```

so the point is finding which columns values match column A, in the above case its column C, so then column C will be dropped and any columns that come after it using df.drop(df.columns[column C index : -1])

end result:

```
#     A      B   
#    0     one   
#    2     two   
#    4     two    
#    6     one  
#    7   three
```

Comment: Add some sample data of what you expect to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
idx = (df.values == df.iloc[:, 0].values[:, None]).all(axis=0)[1:].argmax() + 1
```

Explanation:

- Compare all columns, elementwise, to the first column. Note that the right side adds extra dimension to column values so that numpy can broadcast its values for comparison.

  `(df.values == df.iloc[:, 0].values[:, None])`
- find columns that are all `True`

  `(...).all(axis=0)`
- find index of the first fully matching column besides the first one. Add 1 to compensate for the unused first column

  `(...)[1:].argmax() + 1`